# Can't tell which tab is active anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, answers, tabs

looks like someone got happy with the CSS - you can now no longer tell what
tab is active, e.g. answer tabs:

> [image: no hover]

Even if you hover over an option - it wont show you what tab is currently
selected - it only shows you what tab you are currently hovering over:

> [image: hover]

Comment: Not only answer tab, this happens on question tab too. You can add that in the question.

Comment: Only happens on question tabs on sites that haven't been switched over to the new themes yet (so basically anything that's not SO/MSO/MSE). I pinged a designer to take a look.

Comment: @AdamLear It happens on answer tabs, question tabs, user tabs with old design. Thanks for ping to a designer.

Comment: seems to be happening on MSE and SO too now. unless i'm misunderstanding @AdamLear

Comment: also seems to happen at 10K tools page with Firefox 60.0.2 on Windows 10 (you can check it [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tools) @AdamLear if you're interested)

Comment: @KevinB It's happening for answers (active/oldest/votes) on SO/MSO, but not questions (active/featured/hot, etc).

Comment: @gnat Yeah, that tabs partial is used in a bunch of places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an oversight when switching certain themes to different markup. It's been fixed and will go out in the next build.

Comment: Whoa... smiley alert! ;)