# Selected tab issue in the Users page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

In the [Users page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users), the sub tab option is not selected with the last selected option. I mean the sub tab options as *week/month/quarter/year/all* under **Reputation** and *reputation/creation date* options under **New Users** and so on.

When inspect the sub tab elements, for the selected option the CSS class `is-selected` is applied. But seems like there is no CSS code for the class.

When checking with the Profile page (there the selected tab is highlighted), the class `youarehere` is applied for the selected tab. Replacing the `is-selected` with `youarehere` class name in the users page, the selected tab is displaying as expected.

The issue is in the all main and meta sites of the Stack Exchange.

> [image: Users page]

Comment: Seems related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311502/answer-tab-is-broken-network-wide

Comment: @Pang Yes. I also added the root cause of the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *should* be fixed and will go live in the next build. We were moving some markup around for theming, and this one got lost in the shuffle. Hooray!